# BlockSolve.o Error in Makefile

Tags: compiling, fortran

I am trying to run Enzo Project simulation and have followed the steps listed on the website here: https://enzo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bootcamp.html . I have been getting an error and google searches are not shedding light on what is going wrong on my end. Here is the error I am getting:

```
Compiling BlockSolve.F
gfortran  -c -o BlockSolve.o -fno-second-

underscore -m64 -g -DLINUX -DH5_USE_16_API   -D__max_subgrids=100000 -D__max_baryons=30 -D__max_cpu_per_node=8 -D__memory_pool_size=100000 -DINITS64 -DLARGE_INTS -DCONFIG_PINT_8 -DIO_32    -DUSE_MPI   -DCONFIG_PFLOAT_8 -DCONFIG_BFLOAT_8  -DUSE_HDF5_GROUPS   -DTRANSFER   -DNEW_GRID_IO -DFAST_SIB      -DENZO_PERFORMANCE    -DUSE_UUID -DSAB BlockSolve.F
    
BlockSolve.F:1070:11:

 1070 |       NB = ILAENV( 1, 'UGETRF', ' ', M, N, -1, -1 )
      |           1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'ispec' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(8)
BlockSolve.F:1070:11:

 1070 |       NB = ILAENV( 1, 'UGETRF', ' ', M, N, -1, -1 )
      |           1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'n3' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(8)
BlockSolve.F:1070:11:

 1070 |       NB = ILAENV( 1, 'UGETRF', ' ', M, N, -1, -1 )
      |           1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'n4' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(8)
BlockSolve.F:932:30:

  932 |          JP = J - 1 + e_idamax( M-J+1, A( J, J ), 1 )
      |                              1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'incx' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(8)
BlockSolve.F:2628:18:

 2628 |          ILAENV = IEEECK( 0, 0._RKIND, 1._RKIND )
      |                  1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'ispec' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(8)
BlockSolve.F:2639:18:

 2639 |          ILAENV = IEEECK( 1, 0._RKIND, 1._RKIND )
      |                  1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'ispec' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(8)

make: *** [BlockSolve.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not a Makefile error. **make** has behaved correctly: it has discontinued the build because there are six language errors in your BlockSolve.F Fortran source (three on line 1070 and one each on lines 932, 2628 and 2639).

Fix the compile-time errors and the make will continue to the next phase.

All the errors are associated with passing INT(4) variables to functions that need an INT(8). That might be because the source you downloaded was for an earlier Fortran standard, or for a different architecture to yours.

The document you reference actually states that "This leads to a mismatch: while the C/C++ code will always have the correct bitwidth, the Fortran code must have these variables set properly to ensure the correct bitwidth." and notes that there are four variables that need to be correctly set (such as MACH_FFLAGS_INTEGER_64) and that there are several makefiles provided for differing architectures and OS.

The document also provides a link to an `enzo-users` forum to assist with this kind of problem.